# Raster calculation with conditions in R

Tags: raster, gdal, r, loop, rasterbrick

I have two rasters (A,B) with the same resolution, extent and crs. Now I would like to generate a raster C with the value 1 for each cell that have a value of 30 or higher in A and B. I use a loop, but this approach takes ages, are there faster solutions?

```
library(raster)
A <- raster("A.tif")
B <- raster("B.tif")
C <-  stack(A, B)
C$result<-as.numeric(NA)
C<-brick(C)

for (li in 1:length(C$result)){
  if (!is.na(C$A[li])&!is.na(C$B[li])){
    if (C$A[li]>=30 & dfa$C$B[li]>=30){
      C$result[li]<-1
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the terra package, there is a `terra::ifels` method that mirrors `ifelse`. The terra package is intended to be the replacement for raster. There is only one raster class and the interface function is `terra::rast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a one-liner:

```
C <- A >= 30 & B >= 30
```

That gets you a raster of 0/1. If you want NAs for 0, then do:

```
C[C==0] = NA
```

as well.

Comment: That does exactly the same as my code but it only takes some seconds. Thanks

Comment: Most arithmetic and logical operators and functions will work on raster objects to produce more raster objects.